# How to create XML using for loop

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to create an XML inside the for loop using all the values fetched using for loop.

when for loop runs I get a value for field "user"  and field "IS Active in AD" and I want to store all the values of "user" and "is active in ad" in the below format:

```
<outputs>
<output>
<user>value</user>
<Active>value</Active>
</output>
<output>
<user>value1</user>
<Active>value1</Active>
</output>
'
'
<output>
<user>valuen</user>
<Active>valuen</Active>
</output>
</outputs>
```

Comment: Format I am looking is:  <rows><column></rows>

Comment: What do you mean under for loop? Xslt for?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using javascript with this you can do a foreach loop to do this I just never really used XML so maybe something like this

```js
foreach(var value in User){
   var dataStuff = `<rows><column>{user.name, user.email, etc..} </column></rows>`
  getElementByID("ElementName").append(dataStuff);
```

so I don't know maybe it can be easy like this I don't understand what you really asking for without your code

Comment: I am using XML and building it using XSLT

Comment: that is great but until you give us more information and the fact I never used that it would be wist of you to share some code because I am guessing you can do something like that. Not trying to be difficult I just don't know